# Biomedical Engineering: Applications, Basis and Communications bibtex style .bst file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

is there a *Biomedical Engineering: Applications, Basis and Communications* .bst file?

Reference format:
Author, title, Abbreviated Journal Title (italic type) Volume (boldface): First-page number, Year.

Reference examples:

1. Shieh MJ, Wong JM, Wang CY, Basic principle and clinical application of bipolar electrosurgical polypectomy snare, Biomed Eng-Appl Basis Commun 4:123, 1992.
2. Kolenbramder KD, Dykstra CE, Lisy JM, Torsional vibrational modes of (HF)3: IR-IR double resonance spectroscopy and electrical interaction theory, J Chem Phys 88:5995, 1988.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: What have you tried so far? E.g., have you contacted the journal's editorial office?